# Rsync exclude does not work during remote upload

Tags: rsync, remote, exclude

I prepared an rsync code as below:

```
/home/ra/maindir/subdir/ --exclude="/dir/config" --exclude="/dir/include/x.php" --exclude="/maindir/include/x1.php"
```

What I am trying to do is to exclude 'config' folder and 'x.php','x1.php' files during remote upload. Rsync works well, but exclude. Still my copied folder includes the folder and files that I tried to exclude in rsync. What is wrong in here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution. I replaced double quotes (") with single quotes ('). It works now.